# How to add trailing zeros for cents and a dollar sign ($) to the Y-axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have dollar amounts on the y-axis with a dollar sign ($)  and 2 trailing zeros to indicate cents (for example, $1.00).

I have the following code and the resultant plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df <- data.frame("x" = c("A1",
                         "A2",
                         "A3"),
                 "y" = c(0.77,5.42,8.06))

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x, y), stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0 , 9, 1.00),
                     breaks=c(seq(0,9,1.00)),label=dollar, 
                     expand = c(.01, 0), limits = c(0, 9))
```

[image]

Comment: Literally, change to `label=dollar_format(0.01)` and you get your `$1.00` y-axis label. (I'm assuming that you already have the `scales` package loaded. If not, then `label=scales::dollar_format(0.01)`.)

Comment: BTW, `$1.00` is not *leading* zeroes, it's *trailing* zeroes. Leading zeroes would be `$001` (or `$001.00` combined).

Answer (score 4):

It appears you're already using the `scales` package for `dollar`, there is also a `dollar_format` function *made* for this.

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x, y), stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0 , 9, 1.00),
                     breaks=c(seq(0,9,1.00)),label=dollar_format(accuracy=0.01), 
                     expand = c(.01, 0), limits = c(0, 9))
```

[image]

(If you look at the source for `dollar_format`, it's effectively just a mechanism to set arguments for `dollar` (e.g., `accuracy`, `scale`, `prefix`) and have that return something appropriate for `label=`, as in a *function*.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` to format y-axis :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x, y), stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0 , 9, 1.00),
                     breaks=c(seq(0,9,1.00)),
                     label= function(x) sprintf('$%.2f', x)
                     expand = c(.01, 0), limits = c(0, 9))
```

[image]